# Does a blockchain always need transactions?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

In every article I read that there are transactions in a block. But do I really need them all the time?

E.g. I want to save names of persons in a blockchain, let's say it should be a guest list. Because it's a private blockchain I need no `proof of work`, everyone can create a new block and broadcast it to the other nodes. In this case I see no reason to use transactions because I don't transfer something from A to B.

So in my opinion transactions is a "must have" in most peoples' head because at the beginning the most popular case was crypto currency where you need transactions. And when I use them with a `proof of authority` when and who will make a block with the transactions?

Comment: A transaction is a general term used to indicate for transferring money as well storing data in the blockchain. As the first blockchain was used to transfer money using Bitcoin and later it used to store data too.

Comment: so they kept the logic and just swapped the transaction input. but there is no real benefit in it, isn't it?

Comment: To understand that we have to think of blockchain as a technology which can be used for more purpose. Due to its properties like distributed ledger, Immutability, secure transaction, and pseudo-anonymous, it can be used for other purposes too. Distributed ledger provides the availability of data with no downtime. Immutability allows the data to be never edited or deleted. The transactions are secure and verified by the nodes before adding to block.

Comment: In the end  transactions are also just texts -use anything you want its your Block-Chain